# Is this declaration of an Eigen::Tensor in C++ safe, or buggy? And should I submit an issue for it?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, eigen, tensor

Using Eigen's unsupported Tensor module, if I do:

```
    size_t dim0 = 3;
    size_t dim1 = 2;
    size_t dim2 = 4;
    Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> var(dim0, dim1, dim2);
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorDimensions.h:287:167: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'unsigned long' to 'std::__1::array<long, 3>::value_type' (aka 'long') in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
```

But the code compiles OK if I explicitly cast the dimensions to long int:

```
    long int dim0 = 3;
    long int dim1 = 2;
    long int dim2 = 4;
    Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> var(dim0, dim1, dim2);
```

Questions:

1. For what size variable will this become unsafe? If at all?
2. Surely Eigen should be generally accepting a `(size_t)` type as a dimension argument? Should I file a bug report for this or is it intended behaviour here?

I'm using C++11, clang on Mac OSX (haven't tested other platforms).

Comment: `size_t` for length is not a great idea, the proper types are signed ones for optimization/UB reasons.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that, thank you @Matthieu. For Eigen in general, or just Tensors? And is there an example somewhere of how having a signed tensor dimension can help optimise (it's not intuitive that a tensor dimension could be negative)?

Comment: @thclark In short: Unsigned integers must "wrap around" whereas signed ones are (allowed to be) UB on overflow. The `i < length` check in a `for` loop where `i++` happens every iteration becomes simpler when you can be sure that `i++` never decreases `i` (which might happen from unsigned wraparound). Just one instance where UB gives the compiler better optimization opportunities.

Comment: Ah, yeah that makes sense. Thank you @Max

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Could you check [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54243601) on your comment?

Comment: If `i++` really decreases `i` due to wrap around, the condition `i<length` would already be false before `i` is incremented, or in other words, the loop would have exited in or prior to last iteration. So I don't think it is a good example to illustrate the point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The narrowing warning will appear for any type that cannot be converted to a `long` without loss. So that means `size_t`, but also `long long` on some platforms.

In general, loop indices should be signed, hence Eigen decision to store `long` for sizes.

For more info on this, there are some cppcon topics (Chandler Carruth, mainly) about undefined behavior that help the compiler.

Comment: OK, so the answers are 1) I should be typecasting to a signed type, checking that this doesn't cause an overflow error.
and 2) it's valid and expected that the size arguments to Eigen::tensor are signed, so I shouldn't submit a bug report.

Comment: Exactly, yes. Perfectly valid warning due to how Eigen works (at least that's my opinion).